# PHP excel Maatwebsite giving me random character file name

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

```
\Excel::create("test", function ($excel) use ($logs) {
    $excel->sheet('AllProjectLogHours', function ($sheet) use ($logs) {
        $sheet->loadView('template',
            array('log' => $logs));
    });
})->export('xlsx');
```

I am using Maatwebsite to generate excel.
It returns me excel file named d45e9cfc-ed62-4422-918a-2d3ecb980131. I check create and export function in Maatwebsite  in vendor directory as well.
File name variable set correctly but still it is giving me random character file name

Anyone solved or encounter this problem ?